# How do I use a matched part of the RewriteCond HTTP_HOST in the RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a need match part of a domain name with a regex and redirect to a different domain with the matched part being part of the filename.

Example, in the htaccess on this-is.com:

```
this-is-a-test.com redirects to this-is.com/test.htm
this-is-a-fish.com redirects to this-is.com/fish.htm
this-is-a-duck.com redirect to this-is.com/duck.htm
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^this-is-a-(.*).com$                                                                                                                                         
RewriteRule (.*) http://this-is.com/test.htm [L]
```

But that doesn't work as the RewriteRule only handles the querystring portion and not the host part.

How do I use the matched part of the RewriteCond in the RewriteRule ?

Comment: Are those separate domains you wish to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

For future reference, you should use the percentage sign for the RewriteCond Match:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^this-is-a-(.*).com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://this-is.com/%1.htm [L]
```